# How to clear cache when i enable navigationcachemode?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

i have 2 button in MainPage.xaml 1st button is Play Again which must make the xaml page to refresh or renew(i dont know how to do this), the 2nd button is to go to Question.xaml  and in the question.xaml page there is a back button which will go back to MainPage.xaml which i enable the cache

Answer (score 0):

Relaunch the page using Frame and renmove back entry